# How to convert ImageInputStream to BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to retrieve a image blob from mysql database and converting it back to image file. Iterating mysql ResultSet as:

```
while(rs.next())
{
   byte[] byteArray=rs.getBytes("image_blob");
   InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
   ImageInputStream is = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);
   BufferedImage image_Bf=ImageIO.read(is);
   ImageIO.write(image_Bf, "png",new File("images/"+rs.getString("name")));
}
```

When I compile and run my java class it gives me error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: can you be clearer by providing the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

successfully resloved this issue.Here is correct code for retrieving images from database

```
while (rs.next()) 
            {
                Blob image_blob=rs.getBlob("image_100x100");
                int blobLength = (int) image_blob.length(); 
                byte[] blobAsBytes = image_blob.getBytes(1, blobLength); 
                InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream( blobAsBytes );
                BufferedImage image_bf = ImageIO.read(in); 
                ImageIO.write(image_bf, "PNG", new File(folder_path+"/"+rs.getString("name"))); 
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ImageIO.read(is);` returns null for you.  [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream)) says that means it can't locate an appropriate `ImageReader`, which seems to be a sign of an invalid input.

Actually, your error is in this string: `rs.getBytes("name");`. You are not getting image content to `byteArray`, but rather image *name* in byte form, so `ImageIO.read` fails.

**EDIT:**

If it still fails with same error, then you'll have to debug. Try outputting the byte buffer to the file directly. Do you get a valid image this way? I'm pretty sure `ImageIO` needs a correct image to operate on and convert to PNG.

```
while(rs.next())
{
   byte[] byteArray=rs.getBytes("image_blob");
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("images/"+rs.getString("name"));
   fos.write(byteArray);
   fos.close();
}
```

Comment: yes it's my error but it gives same error at rs.getBytes("image_blob").

Comment: Try to see what you're actually getting from the database. See updated answer.

Comment: updated answer doesn't save file as image(.png/jpg). it save .txt file containing image bytes

Comment: But .txt containing image bytes is essentially the image, just change the extension? It reflects exactly what you get from your blob field, if you can't open the resulting file as an image, you can't convert it using `ImageIO` either. Perhaps the data in your blob field isn't stored as bytes, but encoded somehow - as base64 or hex for example?